# What should we found in a normal JSF session?

Tags: jsf, session

I just noticed today that the session map contains more than what I put in.

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
Iterator attributeNames = sessionMap.keySet().iterator(); 
while ( attributeNames.hasNext() ){
  System.out.println(attributeNames.next().toString());
}
```

I found two unknown objects in my session :  `com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps` and `javax.faces.request.charset`.  Is it normal to find those objects in the session?

I'm asking this because `com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps` gives me serialization errors on server restart.  It looks like it tries to serialize almost everything.

Note : I know I can shut off serialization by uncommenting `<Manager pathname="" />` in the server `context.xml` file.  I just want to know if it is normal to find `com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps` in the session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's normal to find both in the session:

***com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps***:

Starting from JSF 2.2.0, the `com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeContextManager` deals with CDI `@ViewScoped` beans, and stores the active view maps in the session with `ACTIVE_VIEW_MAPS` as a key (`ACTIVE_VIEW_MAPS` is a constant field whose value is `"com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps"` ), in order to keep track of them.

When the session get destroyed they will be destroyed too, you can check the source code of `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent hse)` from [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/application/view/ViewScopeContextManager.java?av=f).

***javax.faces.request.charset:***

In the JSF docs you can find regarding the method [`public String calculateCharacterEncoding(FacesContext context)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#calculateCharacterEncoding(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) of the [`ViewHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html), that:

> Returns the correct character encoding to be used for this request.
>
> The following algorithm is employed.
>
> - Examine the Content-Type request header. If it has a charset parameter, extract it and return that as the encoding.
> - If no `charset` parameter was found, check for the existence of a
>     session by calling `ExternalContext.getSession(boolean)` passing `false`
>     as the argument. If that method returns `true`, get the session Map by
>     calling `ExternalContext.getSessionMap()` and look for a value under the
>     key given by the value of the symbolic constant
>     `CHARACTER_ENCODING_KEY`. If present, return the value, converted to
>     String.
> - Otherwise, return null

While [`CHARACTER_ENCODING_KEY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#CHARACTER_ENCODING_KEY) is a constant field:

> The key, in the session's attribute set, under which the response
>   character encoding may be stored and retrieved.

You can get it's value from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.application.ViewHandler.CHARACTER_ENCODING_KEY), which is: `"javax.faces.request.charset"`